# Debian 7.6 Wheezy Gnome upgrade

Tags: debian, gnome3, gnome-shell

I Downloaded Debian 2 weeks ago I got 7.6. The thing is that it has Gnome 3.4.2, I am aware that it probably won't support Gnome 3.10 and above. I won't put add the Ubuntu repositories, because I don't think that is a safe thing to do, despite the fact that it might work. So is there a way to get Gnome 3.6 or 3.8 for my Debian system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of Gnome 3 are available for Debian Testing. To enable it, you need to alter `/etc/apt/sources.list`

The following lines will backup your /etc/apt/sources.list, update it accordingly and upgrade Debian to testing.

```
# cp /etc/apt/sources.list{,.bak}
# sed -i -e 's/ \(stable\|wheezy\)/ testing/ig' /etc/apt/sources.list
# apt-get update
# apt-get --download-only dist-upgrade
# apt-get dist-upgrade
```